# Taking "half elven" as a multiclass move

Tags: dungeon-world

It is possible for Bard and Fighter to take a Multiclass Dabbler as their first advanced move. Can they take Ranger's Half-Elven move in this case?

For bard the result seems pretty viable - you simple get the other race's starting move. For fighter... there are plenty of races to choose from and now it depends if GM allows a specific cross-breed. Would it be sane to make human-dwarf hybrid (even though the move is called half-elven)? What about elf-dwarf hybrid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, so long as the Bard or Fighter in question is a human or an elf, since the only condition on **Half-Elven** is that you chose elf or human and could have chosen the other. Any other race choice invalidates that condition—and of course, any class that doesn't have both human and elf as racial move choices also doesn't meet the requirement (and makes Half-Elven useless besides).

**Half-Elven** is specific to human and elf moves though, so no other mix of races are a valid choice or condition for taking the move, so no other crossbreeds work.

There's no restriction on choosing **Multiclass Dabbler** as your Fighter or Bard's first advanced move either, so there are no issues on that front. (Note that this *is* an issue if you're a class that doesn't get Multiclass Dabbler until level 6, since Half-Elven can only be taken if it's your first advanced move and level 6 is far too late for that.)

All this is subject to alteration by already-established fiction, of course. The rules give you a default and I've described that, but anywhere this description obviously contradicts already-established facts of your game, the fiction takes precedence. For example, if you have a dwarven Fighter and in the party's travels you've met half-dwarves-half-humans, then it's a fair adjustment for your GM to let **Half-"Elven"** be used to permit discovering your dwarf's distant human heritage. If such facts aren't already part of the game though, the move doesn't offer any help adding such facts because it's just about elves and humans by default.

Comment: Do you mean that if our world includes half-dwarves, a cleric can at level 6 take multiclass dabbler to become a half-dwarf?

Comment: @aragaer You've got the right idea, but it doesn't work for the Cleric because by the time they can take Multiclass Dabbler at level 6, Half-Elven is not legal to choose (since it can only be chosen as the very first advancement someone takes). It works as I wrote for Fighter because they have both Dwarf and Human moves and can take Multiclass Dabbler at level 2 to get Half-"Elven" ("Half-Dwarven") as their first advanced move. Assuming Half-Dwarves exist in the world and the GM is cool with it, of course.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, Multiclass dabbler can be your first advanced move.**

There are no restrictions on what order you take the advanced moves beyond their level brackets. Multiclass dabbler is in the 2-5 bracket and can be taken at level 2.

**No, you cannot take the Ranger's Half-Elven move with Multiclass dabbler**

In short, because taking Half-Elven requires having taken the Ranger human or elf starting move. You could take Half-Elven with Multiclass Initiate later on if you use multiclass dabbler to take the human or elf starting move from the Ranger class.

**I would not allow a PC who did not start the game as a human or elf to take half-elven via the above method.**

One of the principles for the GM to follow is:

> *Begin and end with the fiction*
>
> Everything you and the players do in Dungeon World comes from and leads to fictional events. When the players make a move, they take a fictional action to trigger it, apply the rules, and get a fictional effect. When you make a move it always comes from the fiction.

Simply put its not staying true to the fiction of the story or Dungeon World's core ethos.

Comment: So basically you have to multiclass to a ranger first and become a half-elf after that. What is a fictional event for multiclassing? I thought it is usually some kind of training. What is a fictional event of becoming a half-elf? I can only think of an "unexpected reveal".

Comment: Your group's mileage may vary, but I'd imagine that you knew you were a half-elf all along, but you suddenly become in touch with your "essential half-elf-ness" and unlock it's full potential.

Answer (score -1):

I see two questions you ask.

First question: is it possible to choose Half-Elven as a move for Multiclass-Dabbler/Initiate?

My answer is: **yes**, you can pick it at level 3 or later given that you have not picked a Ranger move using Multiclass Dabbler before. In this case this would be your first advancement in your "Ranger multiclass".

Second question: is it possible to choose another race than Elf/Human this way?

My answer is: by the rules, **no**. The move specifically states that if you picked either the Elf or Human starting move, you get the other in addition. 
**However**, if your GM and group agree to do so, you can alter the move to allow any combination of races and the appropriateness/consequences/limitations will be up to your fictional setting.

Comment: but wouldn't you then be unable to choose the move, as you have already picked one move on level 2, and Half-Elven can only be picked as the first (!) move?

Comment: Well you are right but you treat your level one lower, and thus theoretically it is your first advancement in your ranger multiclass i would say.
Additionally, technically the condition *on the first advancement* is not part of the move itself, thus need not be applied to multiclass dabbler

Comment: "Ranger multiclass"? I thought that I only get one move when I multiclass, not the whole class. Otherwise it would be possible to take "half-elven" move at any other level as long as I didn't take any other ranger move. Also there is no level requirement for "half-elven", you don't really need to be level 3 for it since it doesn't require level 2. Thus I thought "first advancement" means THE advancement you get when you gain level 2.

Comment: I would rule that you can, in fact, take that move with the advancement you get when you gain level 2, yes. But I would not allow it to be chosen later (Level 3+). That's my point, though, I can easily see @iraserd's way to be true. It depends on your gm, I'd say, but it would theoretically be possible.

Comment: @aragaer no you dont get a real multiclass  of course, but this is the way i would interpret the rules to see how multiclass dabbler interacts with half elven. I put it in parenthesis to clarify that

Comment: @patta might be an interpretation, though i'd rather tend to see it as a level 2-5 move with a condition thus making it available at precisely level 3 or level 3 and later if you want to omit the first advancement condition

Comment: or yes seeing it as your first advancent in the ranger class at any point if it is your first ranger multiclass move might be the most suitable interpretation. I like your comments so that i adopted the answer to reflect that

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but as far as I was aware you could only take each advanced move *once*. So how are you proposing that the Fighter/Bard take Multiclass Dabbler _again_ to get Half-Elven? Getting a Ranger move doesn't suddenly make you a lv2 Fighter/lv1 Ranger, it makes you a lv2 Fighter with a single move from the Ranger playbook. The "level you took this move -1" refers to spellcasting ability only.

Comment: @Aiken I don't really understand what you want to say. You don't take Multiclass Dabbler again, but if you take Multiclass Initiate and you have taken a Ranger move before that was not Half-Elven, I would interpret that as your "second advancement" in your "ranger multiclass". In Parenthesis for there are no multiclasses in DW.

Comment: To play devil's advocate then, give me a clear reason why our hypothetical Fighter should be disallowed from taking **Half-Elven** as their **Multiclass Dabbler** choice? Assuming they were a human or elf. Nowhere in **Half-Elven** does it state the character taking the move must be a Ranger. Only that they must be a human or elf (and by extension have had the option to be the other) and that they take the move as their first advancement.

Comment: @Aiken I think my answer might not be clear enough. I did not say that you cannot pick Half Elven with Multiclass Dabbler?